# HTTP/2 Server Push not working for JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, cloudflare, http2, server-push, cloudflare-workers

I am trying to implement HTTP/2 Server Push through CloudFlare Workers using below code:

```
let mainScript='main-es2015.e66dc0bc532401d980dc.js';
response.headers.append("Link", "</"+mainScript+">; rel=preload; as=script;");
```

I have also tried adding crossorigin

```
response.headers.append("Link", "</"+mainScript+">; rel=preload; as=script; crossorigin;");
```

But its not working.

In first case, the Developer console does show that file is being Pushed from the CloudFlare server along with html response.
but the browser doesnt use that file and makes a duplicate request to download the file again.

In second case, the Developer console shows that the browser does honor the preloaded header, but the contents of the 
file are not pushed from Cloudflare server and the browser has to make seperate request to pull javascript file, 
although it makes the request immediately after receiving the html file.

What I want is the cloudflare server to push the file and browser to use that pushed file without making a duplicate request?

Surprisingly, below code works perfectly for css files:

```
  response.headers.append("Link", "</styles.1d228f78d240e617dd5e.css>; rel=preload; as=style;");
```

but doesnt work for any other content like javascript font files, images etc.

Can anyone please guide what am I missing here?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about your set up. Are you using just one domain or do you have an "assets" sharded domain? Where are you pushing from - the main HTML request? How is your JavaScript referenced in the HTML - with crossorigin attribute or without?

Comment: I am using just one domain and loading all resources from same domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed offline you had two issues:

**Your fonts were being double downloaded instead of using the Pushed versions**

Fonts need the `crossorigin` attribute in the link header or the push will be ignored. See this answer: [HTTP2 pushed webfonts not used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46401942/http2-pushed-webfonts-not-used)

However, even when you added that it appears that Cloudflare stopped pushing so maybe they don't support that.

**Most of your JavaScript files were similarly being double downloaded instead of using the Pushed versions**

This is because you were specifying them as modules:

```
<script src="main-es2015.e66dc0bc532401d980dc.js" type="module"></script>
```

Instead of as simple script files:

```
<script src="main-es2015.e66dc0bc532401d980dc.js"></script>
```

The ones that were successfully pushed, were not defined as modules. Changing the link header to `as="module"` seems to work in Chrome, but [this is not in the `preload` specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/preload/#as-attribute), and [looks like an alternative is under discussion](https://github.com/w3c/preload/issues/136) so not sure how supported that is or if it will continue to be supported.

Comment: Thank you so much Barry, really appreciate your help. For fonts I had to use as=woff2 and it started working even without crossorigin.